# Polymer multiple variables next to each other in template

Tags: javascript, polymer, mustache

My date object:

```
date = { day: '05' }
```

This:

```
<div>{{date.day}}</div>
```

gives me the following HTML output:

```
<div>05</div>
```

Which is fine.

Now, I would like to do this:

```
<div>{{date.day}}. {{date.day}}</div>
```

Which should look like this:

```
<div>05. 05</div>
```

What I get is an empty string. Why is that?

I found an [article](http://ng-learn.org/2014/12/Polymer_Templates-Logic/), which uses the exact same syntax:

```
<div>{{i + 1}}. {{fruit}}</div>
```

I am using Polymer 1.0. The content is surrounded by a `<template>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Polymer 1.0, binding to text nodes is only supported [if the binding fills the entire tag](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#binding-to-text-content). No whitespace or multiple tags are possible at the moment.

You have two options:

```
<div>{{fillMyContent(date.day, date.day)}}</div>
```

Where you define some function `fillMyContent` which returns the desired value.

Or:

```
<div><span>{{date.day}}</span>. <span>{{date.day}}</span></div>
```

Use individual dummy elements which you can fill fully.

Comment: If you change the definition of "production", it's ready alright... ;)

Answer (score 2):

The article that you reference used an older version of Polymer. In 1.0 that you are now using, this syntax is no longer supported. This is explained in the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#binding-to-text-content)

> The binding annotation must currently span the **entire content** of the tag.

You can use [computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed) to achieve the same result.